# Split a text file based on delimiter using linux command line

Tags: awk

I have a file with the following lines of text:

```
jeremy , thomas , 123 
peter , paul , 456 
jack , jill , 789
```

I would like to remove all of the data except for the center item. For example ending up with a file which contains:

```
thomas
paul
jill
```

I have tried so many awk patterns my brain is exploding. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @MattBall because cut doesn't let you specify a multi-character string like ` , ` as the field delimiter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `awk`:

```
awk -F '[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*' '{print $2}' input.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me but using actual space characters does

Comment: @Necrolyte2 then you must be using old, broken awk (/bin/awk on Solaris). Use a different awk, e.g. /usr/xpg4/bin/awk on Solaris or nawk.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
cat <filepath> | tr -d ' ' | cut -d',' -f2
```

Comment: I guess this is assuming you are not forcing yourself to use awk

Comment: No I wasn't forcing myself to use awk, it just seemed the correct tool. Now I realize I was way off base. Thank you for the simple solution.

Comment: I wouldn't say you were way off base. kev has a good pure awk solution.

Comment: @user1488639 awk is absolutely the right solution. The one you've selected as correct uses cat for no reason, has 2 unnecessary pipelines, will remove spaces within columns, etc.

Answer (score 1):

grep look around:

```
grep -Po '(?<=, ).*(?= ,)' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ cat (your file)| cut -d ',' -f2 > (new file)
```

for instance:

```
$ cat /home/file1.txt | cut -d ',' -f2 > /home/file2.txt
```